# Need a regex for matching one of multiple classes

Tags: html, css, regex

I'm upgrading all my websites and have redesigned them so that all the URL's default to lower case, which forced me to also change all my image names and paths to lower case. The regexes I used did the job. Unfortunately, they changed a lot of other things to lower case as well.

For example, this is what a typical div looked like before:

```
<div class="Cool R P Wx500">
```

And this is what SOME of them look like now:

```
<div class="cool r p wx500">
```

I emphasized SOME, because some div's (and other tags) were changed and others weren't.

So I'd like to find a regex that will help me search for a particular class - e.g. Cool, R or Wx500. It's a little tricky because 1) my classes aren't always listed in a particular order, and some class names consist of a single letter (e.g. B = border and R = float to the right).

So I guess what I'd like to be able to do is search for div's that include the class "Cool," then search for div's that include the class "R." It would also be helpful if I could make my searches case sensitive. For example, I might need to search for div's with the class R - but only in cases where it was changed to lower case (e.g. [div class="cool r"]

Can that be done? Dreamweaver has a pretty good regular expression utility, but it can't pick one class out of a series, as far as I know. I'm working on a Mac, and Dreamweaver and TextWrangler are my primary text editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
(class=".*?\b)r(\b.*?")
```

Instead of `r` use the class that you want to search for and replace with `$1new$2` where `new` is the new class name that you want.

Explanation:

- `.*?` non-greedy match any character.
- `\b` match word boundary (`"` counts as a boundary).
- () group, the first part will be in group 1 ($1), the second part in group 2 ($2)

For example the following will be matched:

```
<div class="r">
<div class="r cool p wx500">
<div class="cool r p wx500">
<div class="cool c wx300 r">
```

But the following will not be matched:

```
<div class="runcool c wx300">
<div class="uncool cr wrx300">
<div class="uncool c wx300r">
<div class="R">
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't use lookbehind unless the length of the matching substring is known at compile time. In this case the `.*?` inside the `(?<=)` means it won't work. I don't know Dreamweaver, and it's possible that the rules are different from what I'm used to, but I doubt it. Also, you don't need lookarounds to replace a substring - the normal way to do this would be with capture groups.

Comment: @DavidKnipe - Thanks, my regex utility was set to .NET which does support  infinite repetition inside lookbehinds. I have updated to use capture groups, I just thought that it would simpler for the replace expression using lookarounds, but you are right the group approach is more standard.

Comment: @ acarlon - Awesome! I just wanted to add that it didn't work in TextWrangler (for me). Actually, it appears to make the correct matches but not replacements. But it works perfectly in Dreamweaver. On my first try, there was just one minor error - it also replaced your very last example, the one with the capital R. However, Dreamweaver lets you check a "Case Sensitive" box when doing regex operations. When I checked it, your script worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If Dreamweaver doesn't support lookarounds (I don't have a copy to test with), you should also be able to use this:

*using cool as an example class*

Find `(<div ([^>]+ )?class="([^"]+ )?)cool( |")`

Replace with `$1Cool$4`

Since `$1`/`$4` means "everything matched by the first/fourth subexpression in parentheses".

Comment: That's assuming properties are all seperated by spaces.. if there are tabs mixed in you'll want `(<div\s([^>]+\s)?class="([^"]+\s)?)cool(\s|")`